# Subtracting two dates and taking months as output in MS SQL 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help to solve the issue.

I have Employee Table from that employee table details required are:

`EmployeeName,no of months worked`

no of months are calculated by resignation date - joining date which consists in the same table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**DATEDIFF()**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) function

```
DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)
```

In query do this

```
Select EmployeeName,
       DATEDIFF(mm,joiningDate,resignationDate) as monthsWorked
From table name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get all days and hours

```
declare @StartDate DATETIME = '2013-04-05 10:45:41.013',@EndDate DATETIME = '2013-04-07 14:45:41.013'
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh,@StartDate,@EndDate)/24 AS 'Days'

          ,DATEDIFF(hh,@StartDate,@EndDate) - 

          (DATEDIFF(hh,@StartDate,@EndDate)/24)*24 AS 'Hours'
```